# Why raspberry pi is really terribly slow even it has an arm processor

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi4

I feel like I am asking a stupid question. The question is simple. Why raspberry pi 4 gb is so slow(slower than x86 processor) even it is using a arm processor?

I am using raspbian 32 bit.

Comment: The mere fact that a CPU uses the ARM architecture says nothing about its speed, no more than the fact that it is x86.  Your Raspberry Pi is certainly faster than *some* x86 CPUs, and slower than others.

Comment: Then why apple's M1 gained much popularity in terms of speed

Comment: Because it's a *particularly fast* ARM CPU.

Comment: The pi is based off of a low performing set top box/tablet/phone type chip.  In no way shape or form can it compete even with a laptop x86. The car vs motorcycle comparison is not really even fair as motorcycles outperform cars in many ways (as do cars to motorcycles)  it is more like a bicycle vs car comparison.  Developed for different purposes, etc.  Just because both have a seat that fits a human butt and have some rubber tires, doesnt mean they are comparable.

Comment: The M1 is going to compete favorably in some ways to other similar products and negatively in others.  And it may be the final nail in the Apple laptop business which has/had stalled, or it may be a boost, but not with the first chip that will just be a stepping stone to get them to the next one or two.

Comment: This market is not necessarily for games or other, it is for folks to skype, zoom, check email, social media, etc.  Same things they can do with their phone but with a keyboard and bigger screen and it will do just fine for that market, if not every well compared to the x86s configured for that market.  You will easily be able to spend much less money for an x86 based laptop that will run circles around the m1 based mac in targetted benchmark tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't just one ARM processor, in the same way that there isn't only one x86 processor, so the answer will be a huge multi-dimensional table comparing different processors against different situations.

---

A similar question is "Why are cars faster than motorbikes?", the answer is...a lot of questions; what's the engine of the car? and the one in the motorbike? do they have turbo? are we on a circuit or off-road? what was the budget? how much petrol do we have? etc, and... what about the driver?